# RecyclerView + Adapter is not visible after create first time on Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have one fragment and this contains a RecyclerView and this is populate with retrofit 2, in my Listener is populate the adapter and set on the RecyclerView.

if the app is killed and start again, the first time when i open this fragment is shown correctly but if i press **back button** or if change the fragment, when i try to get into the same fragment the RecyclerView with the adapter is never shown.

i'm using this on gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
```

this is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    layout="@layout/standard_toolbar" />

<com.sample.ui.CustomSwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/ptr_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/empty_rewards"
            layout="@layout/no_near_by_rewards"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rewards_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</com.sample.ui.CustomSwipeRefreshLayoutt>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my fragment class:

```
public class RewardsListFragment extends BaseFragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

public static volatile boolean refreshOffersListFragment = false;
public static boolean comingFromDetailFragment = false;
private static GoogleApiClient locationClient;

private int LIMIT = 7;

private View noRewards;

ArrayList<MerchantListItem> nMerchantList = new ArrayList<>();

private RewardsRVArrayAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView rList;

// Bool to track whether the app is already resolving an error
private boolean resolvingError = false;
private boolean awaitingPermission = false;
private boolean appSettingsSelected = false;
private boolean locationSettingsSelected = false;
private boolean gpsOffScreenDisplayed = false;
private boolean awaitingHomeCoordinates = true;

private double homeLatitude = 0.0;
private double homeLongitude = 0.0;
private Location currentLocation = null;
private String permissionStatus;

MerchantListRequest listRequest;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.rewards_list_fragment_2, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    rList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(rewards_list);
    noRewards = view.findViewById(R.id.empty_rewards);

    rList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    if(mAdapter != null)
    {
        mAdapter = null;
    }

    if(rList.getAdapter() != null)
    {
        rList.setAdapter(null);
    }

    if(listRequest != null) {
        listRequest.getCall().cancel();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    homeLatitude = ChimeApplication.user.latitude;
    homeLongitude = ChimeApplication.user.longitude;

    startIndeterminateProgress();
    currentLocation = new Location("");
    currentLocation.setLatitude(homeLatitude);
    currentLocation.setLongitude(homeLongitude);
    awaitingHomeCoordinates = false;

    mAdapter = new RewardsRVArrayAdapter(new ArrayList<MerchantListItem>());
    rList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getRewards();
}

private void refreshOffers() {
        startIndeterminateProgress();
        final int first_row = 0;
        final int num_rows = LIMIT;
        listRequest = new MerchantListRequest(parentActivity, currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), first_row, num_rows);
        listRequest.execute(new MerchantListRequestListener(getContext()));
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    refreshOffersListFragment = true;
    refreshOffers();
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.offers_list_menu, menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.refresh) {
        refreshOffersListFragment = true;
        refreshOffers();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (locationClient != null && locationClient.isConnected()) {
        locationClient.disconnect();
    }
}

private void showList() {
    noRewards.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    rList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void hideList() {
    noRewards.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    rList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private void setMerchantsList(ArrayList<MerchantListItem> results) {

    if (nMerchantList != null && nMerchantList.size() > 0) {
        nMerchantList.clear();
    }

    for (MerchantListItem item : results) {
        nMerchantList.add(item);
    }

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new RewardsRVArrayAdapter(nMerchantList);
        rList.setAdapter(null);
        rList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.addAll(nMerchantList);
        rList.postInvalidate();
    }
}

private class MerchantListRequestListener extends BaseRetrofitRequestListener<MerchantListResult> {

    public MerchantListRequestListener(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestFailed(int code, String errorMessage) {
        android.util.Log.e("RECYCLERVIEW", "FAIL request");
        stopIndeterminateProgress();
        dialogCheck();
        if (errorMessage != null && !errorMessage.isEmpty() && isVisible()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideList();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccessful(Response<MerchantListResult> response) {
        dialogCheck();
        stopIndeterminateProgress();
        if (response != null && response.body().results != null) {
            showList();

            setMerchantsList(response.body().results);


        } else {
            hideList();
        }
    }

    private void dialogCheck() {
        if (!Utils.isHighAccuracySet(parentActivity) && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(parentActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(parentActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            displayGPSOffDialog();
        }
    }
}

private void getRewards() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(parentActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (!(RewardsListFragment.this).shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                awaitingPermission = true;
                (RewardsListFragment.this).requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        PermConst.REWARDS_LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUESTED);
            }
        } else {
            displayPermissionDeniedDialog();
            final int first_row = 0;
            final int num_rows = LIMIT;

            listRequest = new MerchantListRequest(parentActivity, currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), first_row, num_rows);
            listRequest.execute(new MerchantListRequestListener(parentActivity));
            awaitingPermission = false;
        }

    } else {
        if (locationClient != null && !locationClient.isConnected() && Utils.isHighAccuracySet(parentActivity)) {
            // Turn off no offers and gps disabled screens only if the no offers screen is not currently displayed.
            locationClient.connect();
        } else {
            if (locationClient == null && Utils.isHighAccuracySet(parentActivity)) {
                refreshOffersListFragment = true;
                locationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(parentActivity.getApplicationContext())
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
                locationClient.connect();
            } else {
                final int first_row = 0;
                final int num_rows = LIMIT;

                listRequest = new MerchantListRequest(parentActivity, currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), first_row, num_rows);
                listRequest.execute(new MerchantListRequestListener(parentActivity));
                if (!Utils.isHighAccuracySet(parentActivity)) {
                    gpsOffScreenDisplayed = true;
                }
            }
        }
        awaitingPermission = false;
    }

    mPullToRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);

}
```

And finally this is my adapter:

```
public class RewardsRVArrayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RewardsRVArrayAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<MerchantListItem> results;
private final int sdkVersion;
private Bitmap defaultImage;
private final DecimalFormat dollarFormatter = new DecimalFormat("$##.##");

private int lastAnimatedPosition = -1;

public RewardsRVArrayAdapter(List<MerchantListItem> results) {
    this.results = results;
    sdkVersion = Utils.getSDKVersion();
    setHasStableIds(false);
}

@Override
public RewardsRVArrayAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    defaultImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(parent.getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.big_text);
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rewards_list_item, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
}

@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MerchantListItem offerItem = results.get(position);
    Deal deal = offerItem.deal != null ? offerItem.deal : null;

    if (offerItem.type.equalsIgnoreCase(Const.MERCHANT_MERCHANT_STRING)) {
        setMerchant(holder, offerItem, deal);
    } else if (offerItem.type.equalsIgnoreCase(Const.MERCHANT_REWARD_STRING)) {

        setCategoryReward(holder, deal);
    }

    //Set up the banner
    if (offerItem.banner != null && offerItem.banner.text != null && !offerItem.banner.text.isEmpty()) {
        holder.banner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.banner.setText(offerItem.banner.text);

        //Set color of banner based on type
        if (offerItem.banner.type.equalsIgnoreCase(Banner.TYPE_FEATURED)) {
            holder.banner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow_banner);
            holder.banner.setTextColorRes(R.color.text);
        } else if (offerItem.banner.type.equalsIgnoreCase(Banner.TYPE_PERSONALIZED)) {
            holder.banner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_banner);
            holder.banner.setTextColorRes(android.R.color.white);
        } else if (offerItem.banner.type.equalsIgnoreCase(Banner.TYPE_LIMITED)) {
            holder.banner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.orange_banner);
            holder.banner.setTextColorRes(android.R.color.white);
        }

        //For some reason padding did not work in XML so I moved it here
        holder.banner.setPadding(Utils.convertDpToPixel(10, holder.banner.getContext()), Utils.convertDpToPixel(3, holder.banner.getContext()),
                Utils.convertDpToPixel(10, holder.banner.getContext()), Utils.convertDpToPixel(3, holder.banner.getContext()));
    } else {
        holder.banner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return results != null ? results.size() : 0;
}

public MerchantListItem getItemAtPosition(int position)
{
    return results.get(position);
}

public void addAll(ArrayList<MerchantListItem> newResults)
{
    this.results.clear();
    for(MerchantListItem item : newResults)
    {
        this.results.add(item);
    }
    dataSetChanged();
}

@UiThread
protected void dataSetChanged() {
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void setMerchant(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final MerchantListItem offerItem, final Deal deal) {
    loadCardImage(offerItem.image_url, viewHolder);
    viewHolder.merchant_name_txt.setText(offerItem.name);

    if (deal != null) {
        viewHolder.merchant_offer_txt.setText(deal.name);
        viewHolder.offer_amount.setText(dollarFormatter.format(deal.promotional_value));
    }
}

private void setCategoryReward(final ViewHolder viewHolder, Deal deal) {
    if(deal != null)
    {
        loadCardImage(deal.category_reward.card_image_url, viewHolder);
        viewHolder.merchant_name_txt.setText(deal.category_reward.card_title);
        viewHolder.merchant_offer_txt.setText(deal.name);
        viewHolder.offer_amount.setText(dollarFormatter.format(deal.promotional_value));
    }
}

private void loadCardImage(String url, final ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    if (url != null && !url.isEmpty()) {
        Picasso.with(viewHolder.main_layout.getContext()).load(url).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE ).fit().networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE, NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(viewHolder.main_layout);
    } else {
        setDefaultImage(viewHolder.main_layout);
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void setBackgroundImage(View view, Drawable drawable) {
    //FIXME we can remove this because we don't support any below to API 16 (JELLY BEAN)
    if (sdkVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    } else {
        view.setBackground(drawable);
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    ButtonTextView banner;
    ButtonTextView merchant_name_txt;
    HeaderTextView merchant_offer_txt;
    ImageView main_layout;
    ButtonTextView offer_amount;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        banner = (ButtonTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.banner);
        merchant_name_txt = (ButtonTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.merchant_name_txt);
        merchant_offer_txt = (HeaderTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.merchant_reward_txt);
        main_layout = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_layout);
        offer_amount = (ButtonTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.reward_amount);
    }
}
```

}

the weird thing is, **this was happening on Android M and N**, but now is happening on Android L, i was reading about some issues with RecyclerView previously with **support library** but i can't find the solution.

attached one gif for check what's the behavior
[Gif bug RecyclerView](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B6Kggs9eMx0XTkcwWWFlN1NfVzQ)

Answer (score 1):

Since i can't check it directly, because your project has many dependencies, i suggest that you log every part of your methods.

I suppose there are some errors on your `getRewards()` method.
If your refresh method is works fine, you can use

```
private boolean firstTime = true;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(firstTime){
        getRewards();
        firstTime = false;    
    }
    else{
        onRefresh();
    }
}
```

instead

Comment: I checked every method, and the getRewards() is working fine, is just checking if the locationClient is not null or connected.

Comment: i'll vote up your answer, for a moment was helpful, but this not solve the problem, because i was asking for permission, and remake my getRewards method and i fixed the issue.

Comment: @DiegoF Thank you, as i mention before this answer is just as a workaround if your refresh method is working fine. I can't replicate the issue though with your code, because you just include limited code while your project has many dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Add following the code in onCreateView in RewardsListFragment

```
mAdapter = new RewardsRVArrayAdapter(new ArrayList<MerchantListItem>());
rList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: no, this still not working, for some reason, when i went out to the fragment and return, the RecyclerView has the reference for the last adapter, and if i try to put null, this not make any change

Comment: then you try onresume also